# FastAPI, RabbitMQ, Celery: what's wrong with the code?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, fastapi

FastAPI app:

```
import fastapi as _fastapi
from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult


app = _fastapi.FastAPI()

celery_app = Celery(
    "worker",
    broker_url="amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672//",
    result_backend="rpc://",
)
celery_app.conf.task_routes = {"celery_worker.test_celery": "test-queue"}
celery_app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)


@app.get("/{word}")
async def root(word: str):
    task = celery_app.send_task("celery_worker.test_celery", args=[word])
    return {"message": "Word received", "id": f"{task}"}


@app.get("/api/result/{task_id}")
async def result(task_id: str):
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)
    # Task Not Ready
    if not task.ready():
        return {"status": task.status}
    # Task done: return the value
    task_result= task.get()
    result = task_result.get("result")
    return {"task_id": str(task_id),
            "status": task_result.get("status"),
            "result": result,
    }
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  ylab:
    container_name: ylab
    build:
      context: .
    command: "uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - api_network
  rabbit:
    container_name: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:3.10.7-management
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    networks:
      - api_network
  celery_worker:
    container_name: celery_worker
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A main.celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO
    networks:
      - api_network

networks:
  api_network:
    name: api_network
```

The root() function works well. I can send messages, return a task id, and see all the messages in the RabbitMQ queue, but the result() function for any task id returns task.ready() == False

Can anyone tell me what is the error in this code?

*Services info:*

*RabbitMQ 3.10.7*

*Celery:*

*celery@415bde516932 v5.2.3 (dawn-chorus)*

*Linux-5.10.0-18-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2023-02-05 12:02:49*

*app: worker:0x7f3679306c20*

*transport:   amqp://guest:**@rabbit:5672//*

*results:     rpc://*

*concurrency: 8 (prefork)*

*task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)*

*[queues]*

*.> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `task_track_started`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_track_started):

> If True the task will report its status as ‘started’ when the task is
> executed by a worker.

But in your code, you don't seem to have anything consuming the tasks that you're placing on the queue. They will stay in PENDING state forever.

I started by writing your code to use automatic task routing, using `<func>.delay` to call a task rather than the lower-level `send_task` method:

```
import time

import fastapi as _fastapi
from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult

app = _fastapi.FastAPI()

celery_app = Celery(
    "worker",
    broker_url="amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672//",
    result_backend="rpc://",
)
celery_app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)

@celery_app.task
def test_celery(word):
    time.sleep(10)
    return word.upper()


@app.get("/{word}")
async def root(word: str):
    task = test_celery.delay(word)
    return {"message": "Word received", "id": f"{task}"}


@app.get("/api/result/{task_id}")
async def result(task_id: str):
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)

    # Task Not Ready
    if not task.ready():
        return {"status": task.status}

    # Task done: return the value
    task_result= task.get()
    return {"task_id": str(task_id),
            "result": task_result,
    }
```

When running the above code, a connection to `/foo` results in:

```
{"message":"Word received","id":"34bfe48d-6ab3-4dec-ad7d-aa567315a609"}
```

A subsequent call to `/api/result/34bfe48d-6ab3-4dec-ad7d-aa567315a609` yields:

```
{"status":"STARTED"}
```

And if we wait for 10 seconds, the same request results in:

```
{"task_id":"34bfe48d-6ab3-4dec-ad7d-aa567315a609","result":"FOO"}
```

---

We've demonstrated that things work correctly when using automatic task routing. So why isn't your original code working? There are three problems:

1. You don't have anything watch `test-queue`.

   You're delivering tasks into `test-queue`, but your Celery worker is watching the default `celery` queue. You need to use the `-Q` argument to have it watch `test-queue` instead:

   ```
   celery_worker:
     container_name: celery_worker
     build:
       context: .
     command: celery -A main.celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO -Q test-queue
     networks:
       - api_network
   ```
2. You don't have any tasks defined.

   If you add the `-Q test-queue` argument from the previous step and restart the environment, attempts to connect to `/foo` will result in the following traceback in your Celery worker:

   ```
   celery_worker    | [2023-02-05 14:12:40,864: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'celery_worker.test_celery'.
   celery_worker    | The message has been ignored and discarded.
   [...]
   celery_worker    | Traceback (most recent call last):
   celery_worker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 591, in on_task_received
   celery_worker    |     strategy = strategies[type_]
   celery_worker    | KeyError: 'celery_worker.test_celery'
   ```

   We can fix that by registering the appropriate task with Celery:

   ```
   @celery_app.task(name="celery_worker.test_celery")
   def test_celery(word):
       time.sleep(10)
       return word.upper()
   ```
3. With the previous two changes, your code will successfully submit the task to Celery and Celery will pass it to the `test_celery` function. However, calls to `/api/result/<id>` will fail with:

   ```
     File "/app/./main.py", line 39, in result
       result = task_result.get("result")
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
   ```

   You need to to modiofy your `result` function so that  it looks more like:

   ```
   @app.get("/api/result/{task_id}")
   async def result(task_id: str):
       task = AsyncResult(task_id)

       # Task Not Ready
       if not task.ready():
           return {"status": task.status}

       # Task done: return the value
       task_result = task.get()
       return {
           "task_id": str(task_id),
           "result": task_result,
       }
   ```

With these three changes, your original code works as intended. The complete modified code looks like:

```
import time

import fastapi
from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult


app = fastapi.FastAPI()

celery_app = Celery(
    "worker",
    broker_url="amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672//",
    result_backend="rpc://",
)
celery_app.conf.task_routes = {"celery_worker.test_celery": "test-queue"}
celery_app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)


@celery_app.task(name="celery_worker.test_celery")
def test_celery(word):
    time.sleep(10)
    return word.upper()


@app.get("/{word}")
async def root(word: str):
    task = celery_app.send_task("celery_worker.test_celery", args=[word])
    return {"message": "Word received", "id": f"{task}"}


@app.get("/api/result/{task_id}")
async def result(task_id: str):
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)

    # Task Not Ready
    if not task.ready():
        return {"status": task.status}

    # Task done: return the value
    task_result = task.get()
    return {
        "task_id": str(task_id),
        "result": task_result,
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. At least it works. I see a new queue with a name like "65cc8bc7-330f-36cf-8ed7-54b9c0a4188f" or something, but there are no messages in "test-queue" at all.

Comment: If your code is working, you will probably never see messages in test-queue because they are consumed immediately. If you stop the `celery_worker` and then hit your webserver, you should see messages start accumulating in the queue.